# typescript default function inside interface

Tags: typescript

This is working

```
interface test{
    imp():number;
}
```

but it is possible to implement a function inside.

```
interface test{
    imp():number{
      // do something if it is not overwritten
    }
}
```

This is not working in typescript for me, but there may be some reserved word, for example default or similar, to implement a function inside an interface that is not overwritten if the default work.

Comment: Interfaces are like Kaiser Soze of Typescript... they go around telling everyone what they can and can't do... until compilation... then just like that... poof..  they're gone.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

No. TypeScript Interfaces are not something available at runtime, that is they are completely absent in the generated JavaScript.

Perhaps you meant to use `class`:

```
class Test{
    imp(){return 123}
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my intention was to create an interface to be used by different classes, but they do not have logic relationship, for use extends. So I am using interface, I look over my question, but I found nothing, I do not know if there was some way. No problem to overwrite / implement the same function in each class, only if there would be more comfortable, thanks for your time, and your book.

Comment: Such a strange answer. Just because the typescript interface doesn't have a direct counterpart in the compiled JavaScript doesn't mean that they couldn't have methods. Classes have methods, and can "disappear" during compilation.

Comment: Interfaces are not available at runtime, but are at compile time. Having default method would be technically possible. And to me it would be a good thing (see C# extensions)

Answer (score 6):

Your needs will be fulfilled by abstract classes

```
abstract class Department {

    constructor(public name: string) {
    }

    printName(): void {
        console.log("Department name: " + this.name);
    }

    abstract printMeeting(): void; // must be implemented in derived classes
}

class AccountingDepartment extends Department {

    constructor() {
        super("Accounting and Auditing"); // constructors in derived classes must call super()
    }

    printMeeting(): void {
        console.log("The Accounting Department meets each Monday at 10am.");
    }

    generateReports(): void {
        console.log("Generating accounting reports...");
    }
}
```

Credits [https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#:~:text=Abstract%20classes%20are%20base%20classes,methods%20within%20an%20abstract%20class](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#:%7E:text=Abstract%20classes%20are%20base%20classes,methods%20within%20an%20abstract%20class).

For more info
[https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#:~:text=Abstract%20classes%20are%20base%20classes,methods%20within%20an%20abstract%20class](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#:%7E:text=Abstract%20classes%20are%20base%20classes,methods%20within%20an%20abstract%20class).

Comment: Classes cannot be extended multiple times, the author was looking for mixins (but at the interface level).

Comment: 6infinty8's comment deserves to be promoted to an answer, with a little expansion. Mixins can provide a form of multiple inheritance. They're not supported naturally in TS or JS, but [the official docs describe a way](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html) of implementing mixins that isn't unreasonably hacky.

Answer (score -4):

I've discovered that Typescript seems to allow an interface and another class or object to share the same name. So you can do this:

```
interface test {
    imp(): number
}

class test {
    static imp() { return 123 }
}

class test2 /* extends something */ implements test {
    imp() { return test.imp() }
}
```

It's a pity TS doesn't support function implementations in interfaces, like Kotlin does, to save us writing the wrapper methods, because it could be implemented quite easily in the underlying Javascript.

Comment: OK, it's not a very good solution, and would be easier to understand if I'd used an object instead of a class, and used a different name from the interface. But everything you wrote is wrong. The above does work. class test has everything in common with interface test, because it's an object that implements the interface (but also happens to be a constructor). Properties can be supported with Swift's delegate pattern (not the same thing as C# delegates).