# Extend Interfaces with logic in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an `Interface` where I'd like to create computed properties that uses other properties.

For example, my `Person` interface has first and last name properties. How can I extend the `Person` interface to provide a new property called `fullName` for all implementors to combine the first and last name properties?

```js
interface Person {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}

class Pilot implements Person {
     constructor(public firstName: string, public lastName: string) {}
}

class Sailer implements Person {
     constructor(public firstName: string, public lastName: string) {}
}

const pilot = new Pilot("Joe", "Alpha")
const sailer = new Sailer("Jane", "Beta")

// Extend `Person` interface to return firstName + lastName?

console.log(pilot.fullName) // Joe Alpha
console.log(sailer.fullName) // Jane Beta
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36110184/typescript-default-function-inside-interface

Comment: Are you asking how do you put an implementation into an interface?

Comment: Yes, it is indeed a duplicate of what @ManosKounelakis referred to

Comment: In the same way that Swift and Kotlin lets you add functions with logic onto interfaces, then all implementors get that method for free unless they want to replace it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go on with the parent class for this case

```
interface IPerson {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}

class Person implements IPerson {
  constructor(public firstName: string, public lastName: string) {}

  getFullName() {
    return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
  }
}

class Pilot extends Person {}

class Sailer extends Person {}

const pilot = new Pilot("Joe", "Alpha")
const sailer = new Sailer("Jane", "Beta")

console.log(pilot.getFullName())
console.log(sailer.getFullName())
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ju9dt4px/).

Comment: Maybe an `abstract` type would make more sense and to make it a getter property: `get fullName(): string {...}`

Comment: @TruMan1 I love the idea!

Answer (score 0):

There's One way to extend the Person interface to add a fullName property is to use a getter:

```
interface Person {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  fullName: string;
}

class Pilot implements Person {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;

  constructor(firstName: string, lastName: string) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }

  get fullName(): string {
    return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
  }
}

class Sailor implements Person {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;

  constructor(firstName: string, lastName: string) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }

  get fullName(): string {
    return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
  }
}

const pilot = new Pilot("Joe", "Alpha");
const sailor = new Sailor("Jane", "Beta");

console.log(pilot.fullName); // Joe Alpha
console.log(sailor.fullName); // Jane Beta
```

Comment: You could even enforce a readonly property to discourage callers from doing extra state management. In the interface, `fullName: string;` to this:`readonly fullName: string;`

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible to bind getter functions to interfaces in TypeScript. But you could use a parent class Person that implements an interface IPerson, to achieve what you want:

```
interface IPerson {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}

class Person implements IPerson {
  constructor(public firstName: string, public lastName: string) {}
  public get fullName() {
    return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
  }
}

class Pilot extends Person {
  constructor(public firstName: string, public lastName: string) {
    super(firstName, lastName);
  }
}

class Sailer extends Person {
  constructor(public firstName: string, public lastName: string) {
    super(firstName, lastName);
  }
}

const pilot = new Pilot("Joe", "Alpha");
const sailer = new Sailer("Jane", "Beta");

console.log(pilot.fullName); // Joe Alpha
console.log(sailer.fullName); // Jane Beta
```